Delete a specific record in JDBC ResultSet rs without going over record by record on rs
If you already have read record in a Java JDBC Resultset rs, suppose it has columns username, id, rollnum, now you want to delete record from Reseultset where username = ‘user1’, can you do it without iterating over Resultset rs one by one? The Resultset is updatable using ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
ResultSet doesn’t have any such methods

Do you want to delete from the ResultSet, or from the database?

Only ResultSet , the row which has USERNAME ,= 'user1'

Well you can do it by wrapping it in a FilterRowSet, but the underlying ResultSet will get completely traversed to populate it. Don't call acceptChanges() if you don't want the delete propagated to the database.
